# Unable to install `nodejs` through `nvm` in Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, node.js, manjaro, nvm

I use `atom` as my text editor. I want to install `nodejs` using `nvm` but I already have `nodejs` package installed in my Manjaro as a dependency of some other package.

I found out that `atom` depends on `apm` which depends on `nodejs>=10` and `npm`. Now the problem is if I try removing `nodejs` and `npm` it is possibly going to break `atom` which is not desirable.

In such scenario, how should I remove the `nodejs` and related packages for them to be installed using `nvm`?

Answer (score 0):

I forced the removal of nodejs and npm using:

```
yay -Rdd nodejs nvm
```

which only removes those packages and not their deps. Then I ran the recommended [nvm installation script](http://curl%20-o-%20https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh%20%7C%20bash):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Note: This works fine I'm guessing as long as the node version you select is always over 10. If its below that I'm sure the deps such as atom wont work properly. This isn't an issue for myself, but it could be in your usecase.